# KVM: DisplayPort 1.4 4K @ 120 Hz single monitor, push button

Tags: monitors, keyboards, mice, kvm

## Hardware

I have the following hardware:

- [ASUS ROG Strix XG43UQ](https://rog.asus.com/ca-en/monitors/above-34-inches/rog-strix-xg43uq-model/) (supports 4K @ 144Hz)
- [UNICOMP Classic 101 Black Buckling Spring](https://www.pckeyboard.com/page/product/UB4041A) (predates the Windows key)
- [Logitech Marble Mouse](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Logitech_Marblemouse_USB)

After ~64 presses of the current push button switch, the keyboard locks up. Physically unplugging and re-plugging the keyboard unlocks it. IOGEAR support wrote:

> If the issue were to persist on the replacement as well with emulation disabled, there really wouldn't be much else that could be done as it would just be a sort of compatibility issue which has been seen before with some "non-standard" keyboards and mice such as wireless, gaming, programmable/smart combos.

I'd like to replace the KVM switch.

## Requirements

The hardware requirements include:

- DisplayPort 1.4 (input x 2)
- DisplayPort 1.4 (output x 1)
- 4K @ 120 Hz (or higher)
- USB 2.0 A or USB 3.0 mice and keyboards
- Physically wired push button switch (3 to 6 feet)
- Supports docking station
- One monitor, two computers
- Detachable cables

Ideally, the firmware can have its intercepted inputs disabled, if any.

Switching must not take more than 5 seconds.

Bonus: Does not let Windows rearrange desktop when switching.

Priced below $500 CAD.

## Existing models

- [IOGEAR 2-Port DisplayPort KVM GCS62DP](https://www.iogear.com/product/GCS62DP/) -- Locks keyboard after ~64 switches, doesn't support 120 Hz.
- [UDP-12AP](https://www.connectpro.com/products/udp-12ap-displayport-1-4-kvm-switch-for-single-monitors-and-2-systems?variant=39809121681541) -- Lacks wired push button switch.
- [Level1Techs](https://www.store.level1techs.com/products/p/14-kvm-switch-single-monitor-2computer-64pfg-7l6da) -- Lacks wired push button switch.
- [iCAN 4K HDMI USB KVM Switch 2x1](https://www.canadacomputers.com/product_info.php?cPath=5_3935_4082&item_id=198515) -- Run away; suppresses key combinations (e.g., <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+Left</kbd>).

The UDP-12AP sales team wrote:

> All of our KVM switches will intercept signals for keyboard presses and mouse clicks/movements, and there's no way to disable them without making significant modifications to the firmware of the KVM switch.

I returned the iCAN KVM that intercepted and suppressed <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+key</kbd>. There was no way to disable that mighty gaff. I'm wary of any KVM switch that intercepts keystrokes or mouse scrolling without the ability to disable interception.

The sales team further wrote:

> One of the ways being that you can connect a serial to USB cable between the KVM switch and one of your computers. From there, you'll just need to open up a serial terminal such as TeraTerm, and make some setting changes to the TeraTerm, and you'll be able to control the KVM switch via keyboard command through serial.

A picture may better help explain my setup:

[image: Computer Workstation]

The keyboard tray is closed 99% of the time. I'm looking for a physical, wired push button switch: no keyboard hotkeys, terminal workarounds, or mouse scrolling.

## Contenders

KVMs that meet all the criteria include:

- [2 Port DisplayPort KVM Switch](https://www.newegg.com/jansicotek-sw204n-dp-displayport-usb/p/1DJ-01AM-00084)
- [Forvido KVM Switch](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B0C8SB37Q3?th=1)
- [CKLau 2 Port USB KVM Switch](https://www.newegg.com/p/3C6-0289-004M9)
- [8K Displayport KVM Switch](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002363253939.html)

A runner-up is pretty close, but falls shy of 4K @ 120 Hz:

- [Generic KVM Switch](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B0BWQ8WJXW?th=1)

## Question

Any other recommendations for a 2-port DisplayPort 1.4 KVM switch that supports 4K monitors at 120+ Hz with a wired push button switch and detachable cables?

Comment: Hi Dave, welcome to Hardware Recs! The UDP-12AP supports serial control (which could be used to create a wired remote control), and the L1Techs supports keyboard commands for switching; can you explain why these are both insufficient replacements for a push-button switch? Also since it sounds like you have some other contenders, it might be worth trying them to see if they work as you need them to.

Comment: I've updated the question to include snippets from the UDP-12AP sales team. A physical push-button switch alleviates any possibility of mucking up the keyboard. For example, I double-tap control sometimes and there are KVMs that use that as the hot key. As much as I'd like to try out all the contenders, I'm hoping someone might have experience they can share, or know of any solid choices. (It's also pretty expensive time-wise and price-wise to buy and return four switches without any guarantees that these companies will honour refunds. I've been burned in the past by refund refusals.)

Comment: Personally I feel that given the limited utility of the scroll lock key, the odds of double-tapping it are extraordinarily low, but I see where you're coming from. I'd probably go with the UPD-12AP, using a button attached to a microcontroller to send custom commands over serial, or the L1Techs KVM, depending on which set of intercepted key commands you find to be less obtrusive; I don't trust no-name KVMs that much. You could also reach out to see their support team[s] to see if it'd be possible to creata  custom firmware that rebinds which commands the KVM intercepts, based on your use case.

Comment: I developed a text editor (https://keenwrite.com/screenshots.html) that uses the scroll lock key to keep the Preview panel in place while navigating the main document text. When I write that the ability to suppress keyboard interception is a requirement, it's to avoid these kinds of issues. I'll ask the UDP-12AP support team again to see if they have any other options. (I suspect they won't make "significant modifications" to their firmware to appease one customer.)

Comment: Gotcha (though if you developed it, surely you can change the keybinds right? :P). You may have more luck with getting a custom firmware out of L1Techs. Also have you looked at [display-switch](https://github.com/haimgel/display-switch)? It may get you what you need at a sufficiently lower cost.

Comment: Needs plug-and-play with physical cables; IT has rather strict policies on software installations. I'm okay with dropping half a grand on a solution that works.